# How to free the memory allocated from C++ in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I called a C++ function named "GenerateCode" in C# to get a pointer to a memory block, (return from a "new" operator ). And after use in C#, the memory block should be released. 
But I tried Marshal.FreeHGlobal(), it always throws exception. 
And also, I wrote a C++ function to free the memory, it always throws exception too. 
I wonder how to do.

C# code

```
[DllImport("Generate.dll", EntryPoint = "GenerateCode", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr GenerateCode([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string ComputerInfo, string ProductKey);

    [DllImport("Generate.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeMemory", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void FreeMemory(IntPtr ptr);


    public string GetRegisterCode(string ComputerInfo, string ProductKey)
    {
        string s = null;
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
        ptr = GenerateCode(ComputerInfo, ProductKey);
        s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr, CODE_LENGTH);
        FreeMemory(ptr);
    }
```

C++ Code:

```
const int LENGTH = 24;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* GenerateCode(char* ComputerInfo, char* ProductKey)
{
char* strAsciiName = new char[LENGTH];
return strAsciiName;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FreeMemory(char* ptr)
{

if(ptr != NULL)
{
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
}

}
```

Comment: "Throws exception". What exception?

Comment: AccessViolationException

Comment: You should not be using IntPtr. Instead use a variation/derivation of SafeHandle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unless you've changed your C++ compiler defaults, the default calling convention (even for dllexport) is cdecl.  You're telling the marshaller to use stdcall.  Although this only matters for 32 bit code.